# Подскажите, как работает этот код

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
SCORES = [
['666', 600],
['555', 500],
['444', 400],
['333', 300],
['222', 200],
['111', 1000],
['1', 100],
['5', 50]
]

def score(dice):
    dice = ''.join(list(map(str, sorted(dice))))
    points = 0

    for i, j in SCORES:
        while i in dice:
            points += j
            dice = dice.replace(i, "", 1)

   return points
```

Меня интересуют следующие вещи: зачем нужен цикл `while` и зачем используется метод `replace`.

Comment: Поставьте принты и посмотрите как работает

Comment: Что за параметр `dice`?

Comment: Или прочтите учебник. While - цикл, выполняется пока элемент, хранящийся в i  присутствует в SCORES. replace -  метод, заменяющий в объекте один символ на другой.

Comment: dice это похоже список с числами из которого патом делают строку

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `while` проверяют есть ли элементы которые присутствуют в `SCORES`,  те что в кавычках.
А с помощью `replace` после увеличения поинтов заменяют то что в кавычках на пустую строку, чтобы отметить как учтенное